# Why don't I need a decrementing loop to fade OUT an Arduino LED?

Tags: for-loop, arduino

I've moved past blinking an LED, and have successfully begun fading an LED using the following sketch.

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    for (int i=0;i<255;i++) {
        analogWrite(12,i);
    delay(10);
    }
}
```

However, I just realized that there's no `for(int i=254;i=0;i--)` to fade OUT. Why don't I need that? Is there something in the `loop()` function that automatically returns to the beginning state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why don't I need that?

**Why don't you?**

Of course you do.  That program makes the LED get brighter slowly, then it turns off instantly, and starts over.  That is a sawtooth profile, and just lame IMO.

Everyone wants their LED to fade smoothly bright and then dim.  This is much cooler:

```
void setup() {
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

boolean fadein = true;
int bright = 0;

void loop() {

  // adjust brightness based on current direction
  if(fadein) {
    bright += 1;
  }
  else {
    bright -= 1;
  }

  // apply current light level
  analogWrite(13,bright);

  // when get to full bright, turn around
  if(255 == bright) {
    fadein = false;
  }
  // when get to full off, turn around
  if(0 == bright) {
    fadein = true;
  }  

  delay(10);
  // The delay is just a placeholder
  // here is where your program could do other useful things
  // in addition to the cool LED fade in fade out
  return;
}
```

Comment: Aha. Now that I have some spots burned into my retinas from staring at the LED, my fade in is very slow, and the fade out seems to be quicker--it still fades, but it's more the quick fade like when you cut power...sawtooth behavior, as you indicate. You solution is quite awesome. Thanks.

Comment: Also...I notice you use `return;` at the end of the loop. None of the sketches I've seen include the `return;`. Is that an optional command that you're including for additional clarity, or does including an explicit `return;` do something special that an assumed `return;` does not?

Comment: I use return; solely for clarity.  You can mash all the indentation and line ends beyond recognition and still know that is where the function returns.  It adds nor subtracts anything to the binary.  Code is not only communication from you to the compiler; code is communication from you to those who may follow.

Answer (score 1):

Your `setup()` and `loop()` are part of a larger program (let's call it a dispatcher for this discussion).  That program calls `setup()` once at the start of a run.  It then executes `loop()`, if `loop()` exits then `loop()` gets called again by the dispatcher.

So, the `for` loop runs once and returns to the dispatcher,`loop` gets called again and the `for` loop runs again.  The for loop appears to be running forever, because the amount of time spent in the dispatcher is minimal compared to the length of time spent in the for loop.

Finally, just for your information, the LED appears to be dimmed because the `analogWrite()` creates a square wave signal on the pin in a format called Pulse Width Modulation (PWM).  The brightness of the LED depends on the PWM's duty cycle, which is the second parameter to `analogWrite()`.

Try a program where the value for the PWM duty cycle is stepped up and down thru a range of values.  Find a delay that causes the LED to go from off to completely on within 5 or 10 seconds (or for whatever interval you want!)

Signed, A Former Graduate TA